# Could not find source file. Importing a `.graphqls` file in Typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack, graphql

I've got a React site with a typescript configuration, it runs using `TS-Node` and `webpack`.

Trying to import a `.graphqls` results in the following error:

```
Error: Could not find source file: '/Users/th/WebstormProjects/project/src/server/graphql/typeDefs/query.graphqls'.
    at getValidSourceFile (/Users/th/WebstormProjects/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:139134:29)
```

Which is strange since the file is there:

```
ls ./src/server/graphql/typeDefs 
index.ts        query.graphqls
```

This is the loader section of my webpack configuration:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(graphqls?|gql)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es2016",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Starting the application works with the following script:

```
import webpack, { Compiler } from 'webpack';

import config from '../webpack.config';
import { hookEvents } from './lib/hooks';
import { server } from './server';

const bundler = webpack(config);

hookEvents(bundler.compilers as Compiler[]);
server(bundler);
```

Where server just starts up the express server:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console,global-require */
import chalk from 'chalk';
import express from 'express';
import http from 'http';
import { AddressInfo } from 'net';
import path from 'path';
import { Configuration, MultiCompiler } from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import { addMiddleware } from '../src/server/middlewares/add-middleware';

import { info, ok } from './lib/logger';

const publicPath = (configuration?: Configuration): string => {
  if (
    configuration
    && configuration.output
    && configuration.output.publicPath
  ) {
    return configuration.output.publicPath;
  }

  return '/';
};

export const server = (bundler: MultiCompiler, config?: Configuration) => {
  const app = express();

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(bundler, {
    logLevel: 'warn',
    publicPath: publicPath(config),
  }));

  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(bundler.compilers[0]));
  addMiddleware(app);
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve('dist/public')));
  app.use((req, res, next) => require('../src/server/router')(req, res, next));

  info('ℹ Starting development server...');

  const serverPort = parseInt(`${process.env.PORT}`, 10) || 8080;
  const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
  httpServer.listen(serverPort, '0.0.0.0', 0, () => {
    const { address, port } = httpServer.address() as AddressInfo;

    ok('✔ Server is up and running @', chalk.underline(`http://${address}:${port}`));
  });
};
```

The strange thing is that this does work on a production build. Which basically only does this:
`webpack(config)`

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Not sure where to look anymore.